# Kernel Crashes while Loading data using tf.data.Dataset.take() from a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

I wanted to Load a CSV file with a Target column and 25 feature columns.I have loaded it via `pd.read_csv()` as a pandas.Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
data = data.astype('float64')
data.shape #returns (6500, 26)
y_train = data.pop('target')
y_train.shape #returns (6500,)
```

Then I used the standard Tensorflow 2.0 procedure to read values from pandas.Dataframe:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((data.values, y_train.values))
```

As the Docs said,I have to load features and targets seperately from the TensorflowSliceDataset. But as soon as i run the **for** loop, it freezes for couple of seconds and suddenly kernel dies without any specific reason.

```
for feat, targ in dataset.take(1):
  print ('Features: {}, Target: {}'.format(feat, targ))
```

I have tried to run the code without the **for** loop but the same thing happens with:

```
tf.constant(data['feature-1'])
```

I don't know what is causing this problem. I have also re-installed the pandas as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite know what your dataset is but it seems it's a compact one. As written in [Load CSV data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) documentation, You don't need to make a `tf.data.Dataset` object in order to feed it to the model. You can directly train your model with your `data` and `y_train` like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf


data = pd.read_csv("./data.csv")
data = data.astype('float64')
data.shape #returns (6500, 26)
data.head() #Just for extra inspection of your data
y_train = data.pop('target')
y_train.shape #returns (6500,)

my_model= tf.keras.Sequential([
  layers.Dense(64),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

my_model.compile(loss = 'mse',
                      optimizer = 'adam',
                      metrics=['accuracy'])
my_model.fit(data,y_train,epochs=10) #starts training your model
```

I've used the same model shape from [Load CSV data](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv) documentation, so you can compare the code later on.

Now , for the `tf.data.Dataset.take(count)` function, this will return only `count` elements of the dataset. for example (using abalone dataset mentioned in the [official docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/csv)):

```
abalone_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((abalone_features.values, abalone_labels.values))
for feature , label in abalone_dataset.take(1):
  print(f'feature: %s and label: %s' % (feature, label))

#This will reutrn: 
#feature: tf.Tensor([0.435 0.335 0.11  0.334 0.136 0.077 0.097], shape=(7,), dtype=float64) 
#and label: tf.Tensor(7, shape=(), dtype=int64)
```

So it's basically doing the loop once. Try this code instead:

```py
feature , label  = next(iter(data.take(1)))
print(feature, label)
```

And also you can check for None types in your `pd.Dataframe`:

```py
abalone_train.where(lambda x: x~=None).shape
#Should return same shape as your original dataframe
```

I hope this would fix your problem. Have a nice day.